# Is there an ethernet network adapter?

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, network-adapter

My embedded/internal wireless network card doesn't pick up enough signal for reliable networking/internet usage. However, if I move closer to the source (the window) it works fine.
A [wifi booster antenna](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0034FAS0K/ref=s9_simh_gw_p147_d0_g23_i5?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-3&pf_rd_r=0YJ2049HZG2P1ZCKQ8N5&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=467128473&pf_rd_i=468294) is an expensive solution to my problem, just as an external network adapter with about 1m in cable lenght would be. All solutions however interface with the computer through a usb adapter, is there no solution that interfaces with my ethernet port instead?

Comment: Before you go into changing hardware, try using inSSIDer to make sure your wireless router is not using a congested channel.  If it is and you move to a clearer channel, your reception may improve. http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/

Comment: A Wired Ethernet port goes to a Wired Ethernet interface and circuitry. It's not as universal as USB, at least not in practice. I suppose maybe in theory you could.. maybe in theory since there are Network Printers I guess maybe they transmit their data over Wired Ethernet. They still need to get power from somewhere. The mains or the power wires from USB. What's your gripe with a USB wireless ethernet adaptor?  You could plug in a new wireless card if it's a desktop.

Comment: You can always get a USB cable to 'extend' your Wifi dongle to the window (or out it).  IS there a reason you don't want to use USB? Or are you trying to do this for free without any hardware purchase?

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing would be a Wi-Fi or wireless bridge. The dumbed down ones are called gaming adapters. At about $50 on average, I don't think they're a whole lot cheaper than the booster you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a DD-WRT compatible router in [client mode](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Mode_Wireless) - not the cheapest option, but you can use it with multiple devices